# Integrating Amazon Web services for a new app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to use Cognito for authentification and s3 to store files (images) for a new app (ionic 3). But AWS isn't simple to use and as soon as I start doing something, I need to read another doc somewhere and end up with 15 tabs of documentation open. With twice as many questions.

Do I need a server (nodejs on EC2), lambda (??) or everything can be serverless (direct access to Cognito and s3)? I wish to implement a subscription system at some point.

The user should have access to a list of images (like an infographic) only if he is subscribed. The app is aimed to be deployed on Play store and iOS.

- Does the user (mail/password) exist ?

  - Is he subscribed (monthly) ?

    - access to the database (read-only)

Comment: You can describe your app in full detail and we can then tell you which AWS services you have to use to implement your app. Given the little detail that you gave, we can say yes, it can be fully serverless.

Comment: @dashmug User should have access to a list of images (like infographic) only if he is subscribed. Does user (mail/password) exist ? -> Is he subscribed ? -> access to database (read only)

Comment: Alternative: Did you try [`Firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/)? The onboarding is a way easier than AWS and provides you everything you need (Auth,Database,Storage).

Comment: @MaiKaY I did an app using it and it is way easier... But Firebase servers are based in US with no choice of European servers. Since the app will store EU user informations and EU laws require you to use EU server (or comply to laws) I can't use Firebase for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the app features that you provided, you can use the following:

1. AWS Cognito for user authentication
2. AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda for your backend REST (or GraphQL) API
3. AWS DynamoDB for database (or Amazon RDS if you want to use an SQL database)
4. AWS S3 for image storage

If your app is really basic, I think you can even skip 2 and 3.